# Power BI. Matrix two columns under one column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

This is the desired layout of the matrix that I need. I need to have two columns under one column:

[image: Desired layout]

However, I ended up with this(I used different values, so the values might be slightly different.):

[image]

With the following columns in the matrix fields:

[image]

This is a sample of the dataset. Total Units sum up columns A and B. The Order column sorts the Status column:

```
STATUS  A        B     Total Units  Order 
ABC     3        0     3            1
DEF     0        6     6            2
ABC     3        2     5            1
ABC     5        6     11           1
GHI     0        4     4            3
ABC     5        3     8            1
DEF     0        9     9            2
```

How do I get my desired layout? Do I need to pivot the table? Or do I need to group certain values together?

Comment: you need to unpivot your data for columns A and B;  Total units should be a DAX measure, not a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, transform your data to this:

[image]

Changes I've made:

- Unpivoted source data for columns A, B, and renamed resulting column as "Unit Type"
- Deleted column "Total Units", it's unnecessary
- Named your table "Data" (you can change it to whatever name you prefer).

Then, write 2 DAX measures.

Measure 1:

```
Units = SUM(Data[Value])
```

Measure 2:

```
% = DIVIDE ( [Units], CALCULATE ( [Units], ALL ( Data[STATUS] ) ) )
```

Then, create a matrix as follows:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Explanation:

- You need to unpivot data to put A and B types into the same column. This will allow you to use them to slice data as matrix rows;
- Total Units is a useless column because we can easily reproduce it with DAX measure, and then it will be dynamic (it will respond to matrix rows, columns, slicers and other interactive controls);
- % formula needs to calculate % of units for a given unit type, but across all Status. We accomplish that by first calculating subtotal units for ALL(Data[STATUS]), and then dividing units by them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for a day and this really helped.

Comment: Good solution - But it kills me how much more complicated this is than an excel pivot table where you'd just need to bring the column header below the values and this works in 1 seconds.

Comment: @RazorSky - actually, this problem has to be solved exactly the same way in Excel. It has nothing to do with the tool (PowerBI or whatever). It's a data structure issue - to work properly, data must be unpivoted. Bringing the column header below the values won't work correctly.